# Google Maps V3 DrawingManager not remembering editable/draggable flags

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set the stroke and fill color of a Google Maps DrawingManager sometime after it's created. I don't know if the DrawingManager was originally set up to have editable and draggable Polygons and therefore I don't want to change the the editable and draggable flags. All I wan't to do is change the color. However, it seems that if I don't provide values for editable and draggable the DrawingManager will automatically set them to false.

This is not how Polygons work. If you create a Polygon and set it to be editable and draggable, then later change its color, it will remember the original flag state.

The documentation isn't clear on what should be expected, but this inconsistency seems like a bug in Google Maps to me. Ultimately, I don't want to have to keep track of the DrawingManager's state separately and pass that around.

Anyone have any insight on why this behaves the way it does?

See this example and note the difference in how the DrawingManager and the Polygon behave. The original polygon is editable but ones that you draw using the DrawingManager aren't.

https://jsfiddle.net/wv9zapud/

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, -70),
    zoom: 5,
  });

  var triangleCoords = [{
      lat: 25.774,
      lng: -80.190
    },
    {
      lat: 18.466,
      lng: -66.118
    },
    {
      lat: 32.321,
      lng: -64.757
    },
    {
      lat: 25.774,
      lng: -80.190
    }
  ];

  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red',
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setOptions({
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    fillColor: 'blue'
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    map: map,
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: 'red',
      strokeColor: 'red',
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setOptions({
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: 'blue',
      strokeColor: 'blue'
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I agree this is not super clear from the docs. Note also that with the drawing manager, you are limited to 2 almost equivalent events for Polygons: `overlaycomplete` and `polygoncomplete`. What I usually do is use the `polygoncomplete` event, get the shape path and create a *normal* Polygon out of it. This way you get access to all events of the Polygon class. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2um0zxct/). You can comment out the `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);` line if you want to stay in drawing mode.

Comment: And re. your question as to why it behaves the way it does, I *think* it is because in your Polygon example, you are changing some options for just that one Polygon, while the `setOptions` of the drawing manager sets options for ALL shapes and therefore if you omit some values, they will use the defaults.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for you're thoughts and example. I agree that `setOptions` should use the defaults for missing parameters _the first time_ (what else could it do?). But when setting new options on the DrawingManager after the fact I'd expect it to stick with the values for the parameters that were set up when it was originally created and only override what has been specifically provided. Which is exactly what Polygon does. In your example you assume editable/draggable true. I want the new polygon to be editable/draggable only if the drawing manager was originally created in that way.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to keep a reference of these options as this was suggested to you already in another comment. Also in the `overlaycomplete` or `polygoncomplete` event listener (see my example again) you could check `event.overlay.draggable`. It will be `true` / `false` if you set it, and undefined if you didn't set it / used the default values. Same for `editable`.

Comment: My main goal was to come up with a cleaner solution then keeping reference to the state (so that when I change the color I can reapply the state). But it looks like that's ultimately what I'll have to do.

Comment: What I said above sounds like a clean solution to me... if draggable or editable was set to true or false, you can get that value. If it wasn't set, it will be undefined. What else would you need?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `drawingManager` `polygonOptions` to not have `editable` or `draggable` defined (the both default to false).

If you want polygons drawn by the `drawingManager` to be editable an draggable, you need to set them to true when you call `drawingManager.setOptions`:

```
drawingManager.setOptions({
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: 'blue',
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jwLeoyna/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, -70),
    zoom: 5,
  });

  var triangleCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red',
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setOptions({
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    fillColor: 'blue'
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    map: map,
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: 'red',
      strokeColor: 'red',
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setOptions({
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: 'blue',
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

Comment: My example is a simplified case. In my actual code I have a DrawingManager but I don't know whether editable or draggable have been turned on or off. I simply want to change the color of the DrawingManager while preserving the original values of the flags. This answer assumes I always want them to be editable and draggable.

Comment: Then you have to keep a reference to the current state, and use that, as those parameters default to `false`.

Comment: Yeah that's ultimately what I'm afraid of. Was just hoping there was a cleaner way. Thanks!

Comment: How are those states being "changed"? You really should have provided a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem in your original question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to write it in a way that emulates the scenario I'm seeing. Maybe if when the DrawingManager is created the editable and draggable flags were set to something like `Math.random() > 0.5`. That way we don't know the original state of the DrawingManager we simply want to preserve it in the following code that changes the color.

Comment: In my actual code the color is being changed in the UI via a color picker. The DrawingManager was created earlier based on some other UI options that I'd prefer not to keep track of.